# How add Storm jars on classpath?

Tags: maven, apache-storm

I am attempting to set up a Storm project for development - following instructions at:
http://storm.incubator.apache.org/documentation/Creating-a-new-Storm-project.html

I have attempted to compile and run a topology (from C:\Users\Simon Reeves\incubator-storm\examples\storm-starter) 
as follows:
$ mvn compile exec:java "-Dstorm.topology=storm.starter.clj.word_count"

Please can you inform me of the follows:

1) Which Storm jars need to be added to the classpath? (the Storm download has many jars)

2) In which directory should the jar files be copied to? How do I determine the classpath?

3) What needs to be added to the pom.xml file - does clojars.org repository and Storm dependency need to be added (in addition to 2).

Answer (score 0):

I guess the [storm-starter pom example](https://github.com/apache/incubator-storm/blob/master/examples/storm-starter/pom.xml) is clear enough.

When developing a topology (local cluster mode), every jar in `<dependencies>` is in the classpath.  Maven will download them automatically.

When the topology needs to be packaged as jar and committed to storm cluster, run `mvm package`. All jars without `<scope>provided</scope>` or `<scope>test</scope>` will be in the standalone package. They will be in the classpath when running on cluster.

Also, any jar in `storm-release/libs/` will be added to the classpath. Note that these jars should not conflict with yours in the standalone package.

1. Put every jar you need developing ur topology in the  part. Note that the `storm-core` jar should be with `<scope>provided</scope>`. (Since there is a storm-core jar in any storm release.)
2. Maven will take care of them. (downloading, managing dependencies, etc.) Just add them in the `<dependencies>` part.
3. If any jar on `clojars.org` is needed, add the following part in pom.xml:

```html
<repository>
  <id>clojars.org</id>
  <url>http://clojars.org/repo</url>
</repository>
```

Answer (score 0):

halfelf's answer is good, but I think might be a little too ahead of what you are trying to accomplish at the moment.

I am also new to all this, so some steps may be unnecessary, but this is how I got it working:

If you are trying to just get the basic example working in local mode, using mvn go to the root directory of the incubator-storm project (https://github.com/apache/incubator-storm)

Then run:

> mvn validate
>
> mvn clean install

If you are still having problems, try `rm -rf ~/.m2/`, then restart the process.

Once thats done, you can go to the starter project: `cd examples/storm-starter`

> mvn validate
>
> mvn compile exec:java "-Dstorm.topology=storm.starter.clj.word_count"

EDIT: I did not need to modify anything to get the storm-starter project to work in local mode, or manually add any libs to the project. Make sure you install all the dependancies as well, I had an old version of ruby installed that seemed to stop it from passing the validate goal.